# in flutter app android I cant register account with flutter app just login ,, the error said "wrong email or password"?

Tags: php, laravel, flutter

i build flutter app and link with laravel php admin on web hosting (hostgrator) . I cant register account with flutter app just login , the error said "wrong email or password" . but when change api with default seller codecanyou api :

```
       {
     "base_url": "https://multi-restaurants.smartersvision.com/",
     "api_base_url": "https://multi-restaurants.smartersvision.com/api/"
     }
```

its working 100% without any problem , just on my api problem .. my api is:

```
    {
"api_base_url": "https://eatandgohost.com/api/",
"base_url": "https://eatandgohost.com/"
}
```

and my .env is :

```
    APP_NAME='Eat & Go'
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:*******************
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    APP_URL=https://eatandgohost.com/


    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=yasserdh_multi_restaurants
    DB_USERNAME=********
    DB_PASSWORD=********

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Maybe you've already done this, but make sure to NEVER post real usernames, passwords, or other secret data (APP_KEY?) to the internet!

Comment: thanks for reply bro , whats mean "sure to NEVER post real usernames, passwords" ?

Comment: Your .env includes the username and password for your database. If that is the actual username and actual password, edit the post and replace them with something else. The `APP_KEY` also looks like something that should be kept private.

Comment: Yes it actual .

Answer (score 0):

if you have the problem with register create account with flutter app mobile about this error **"wrong email or password"** or "**the email is exist** " , just try to change web hosting to "hostinger web hosting" , and problem fixed and mobile flutter register without any problem , thanks for all .

Comment: What you mean with Webhosting were I can find this ?